# Javascript functions randomly don't work

Tags: javascript, ajax, load

I've got the following code in Javascript and sometimes it's just not working:

```
var new_c = 0;
function updateCounter()
{
    var last_c = $("span#counter").text();
    last_c = last_c.replace(",", "");
    last_c = parseInt(last_c);
    if (last_c < new_c)
    {
        last_c++;
        $("span#counter").text(last_c);
    }
}

function refreshCounter()
{
    $("<div>").load("includes/ajax/meter/counter.php",
    {
    }, function() {
        new_c = $(this).text().substr($(this).text().indexOf(";")+1);
        new_c = new_c.trim();
        new_c = parseInt(new_c);
    });
}

window.setInterval("refreshCounter()", 1000);
window.setInterval("updateCounter()", 100);
```

If I alert the `new_c` in the `refreshCounter()`-function after performing the load-call, it sometimes returns an empty message and sometimes it returns the content of the page `counter.php`, which is just a number.

Comment: Could the problem be in counter.php?

Comment: no, actually not. It just reads a variable from the database - always the same. And it always works when I access is manually.

Comment: When it's "not working", have you checked the console for Javascript errors?

Comment: When I look at the "Network" information, it shows that it doesn'teven try to fetch the counter.php file. Only when it works, I also see an entry of this transmission.

Comment: Try adding a random value to the end of your URL: e.g. '"counter.php?" + Math.random();'

Comment: Oh man, that's an awesome solution! :) thank you, works now.

Comment: It's only awesome if you understand why that 'fixed' your problem. The real issue is with idempotence and caching.